# why does png image not show up in JPanel in java using g.drawImage()?

Tags: java, jpanel

so I'm trying to display a png image on a JPanel and the frame runs fine and its the size I want and everything but it doesn't display the image, I don't think its the image im using because I used the same method to display it on another project and it showed up fine. I've also tried to see if g.fillRect(); works and that doesn't show up either so is it a problem with my panel not showing up?

```
package main;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class GamePanel extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage img, subImg;
    private float xDelta = 0, yDelta = 0;
    
    public GamePanel() {
        importImg();
        setPanelSize();
    }
    
    public void importImg() {
        InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/TetrisBlocksTextureAtlas.png");
        try {
        img = ImageIO.read(is);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
    
    public void setPanelSize() {
        Dimension size = new Dimension(200, 400);
        setPreferredSize(size);
    }
    
    
    
     void PaintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
        
        

    }
}
```

Comment: Try calling g.setColor before g.fillRect

Comment: I recommend always to use the `@Override` annotation to annotate a method intended to override another method - in this code `PaintComponent()` is never being called, it should start with a lowercase letter (as is convention for methods in Java) and be `public` - if you had annotated it with `@Override`, the compiler would have given your an error

Comment: @ControlAltDel I tried that and it didn't work but thank you for the suggestion :)

Comment: @user16320675 thank you I changed paint component methods first letter to lower case and it worked :)

Comment: Do yourself a favour - *always* use `@Override` then that sort of thing will never happen again